# ckeditor buttons not showing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following setup for my ckeditor:

```
CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', {
    startupFocus: true,
    extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
    removePlugins: 'forms',
    sharedSpaces: {
        top: 'top',
    },
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'print' },
        { name: 'stuff', groups:['print','preview','find' ]},
        '/',
        { name: 'document' },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
    ]
});
```

but for some reason the print button isn't showing. the plugin is in the folder.  (the same is for preview)

but when I add another plugin (e.g. find), it shows in the toolbar just fine. this is the result in the view:
[image: error]

any clue why it isn't loaded?

Comment: Maybe because of duplicate names 2x print?

Comment: @YannPoiré. nope. tried it first without the `stuff` toolbargroup and had same result

Comment: Sorry I'm not home so can't try much but that all I could see quickly. If it it still unanswered later I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the print button is not available for the inline editor.